# certmgr.exe does not work expectedly in command line mode?

Tags: windows, command-line, certificate, certutil

I'm trying to run the MSDN's sample about WCF basic message security using Certificate. In the `setup.bat` file, there is this line of command:

```
certmgr.exe -add -r LocalMachine -s My -c -n %SERVER_NAME% -r CurrentUser -s TrustedPeople
```

When running the `setup.bat`, it works expectedly but I would like to try each command line manually, the `%SERVER_NAME%` should be replaced with `localhost`, so I tried this directly:

```
certmgr.exe -add -r LocalMachine -s My -c -n localhost -r CurrentUser -s TrustedPeople
```

However instead of executing the command and showing the result message usually known as ***Succeeded***, the GUI version of `certmgr` is shown and does nothing. I expect that the command runs normally as when `setup.bat` is executed (the message `Succeeded` is printed and no GUI is shown).

So what am I actually doing wrong? I also don't know how to perform the above command using GUI instead.

Thank you, also if this is not the right place to ask this question, please some mod here moves it to the right place on *stackexchange* network. Please don't close it. Thank you!

Comment: **certmgr.msc** or **certmgr.exe** ?

Comment: well may be I just typed it `certmgr` without any extension.

Comment: I've found why it's like so. In fact what I did before was via the `CMD` which does not recognize the `certmgr.exe`, but when typing just `certmgr` the `certmgr.msc` might be invoked instead. However in `Visual Studio Command Prompt` we can just type `certmgr` or `certmgr.exe` - both are fine. Thank you @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like

Comment: there is no certmgr.exe in windows so better try avoid it

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like yes, but it's packed with Visual Studio tools, it's quite a different thing from `certmgr.msc` which is present in Windows.